# The code get an error: (while computer_cards_total < 17:) NameError: name 'computer_cards_total'

Tags: python

When I run my code through I get an error "NameError: name 'user' is not defined". I don't know what to change/add to fix this error.

I've tried to make different versions of the code and none of them worked. This one does looks like it would do what I want, but 'user' is not defined.

```
import art

import random
def one_cards_func():
  return random.sample(set([11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]), 1)

def two_cards_func():
  return random.sample(set([11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]), 2)

def calculate_score(cards):
  return sum(cards)

    

def play_blackjack():
  
  print(art.logo) 

  # I tried to define de variable as global but still didn't work...

  global computer_cards_total
  player_card_list = two_cards_func()
  player_card_total = player_card_list[0] + player_card_list[1]
  if player_card_total > 10 and player_card_list[1] == 11:
    player_card_list[1] = 1
  
  print (f"Your cards: {player_card_list} you have {player_card_total} Points.") 
  computer_cards_list = one_cards_func()
  print(f"Computer's first card is: {computer_cards_list}")
  get_another_card = input("type 'y' to get another card or type 'n' to pass: ")
  if get_another_card == "y":
    player_card_list += one_cards_func()
    player_card_total += player_card_list[2]
    if player_card_total > 10 and player_card_list[2] == 11:
      player_card_list[1] = 1
    computer_cards_list.append(one_cards_func())     
    computer_cards_total = calculate_score(computer_cards_list)
    print(f"your cards: {player_card_list} your current score: {player_card_total} ")
    print(f" computer card is: {computer_cards_list} with a score {computer_cards_total}")
    if player_card_total <= 21 and player_card_total > computer_cards_total:
        print ("You win!!!")
        continue_play = input("do you want to play again? 'y' or 'n': ")
        if continue_play == "y":
          play_blackjack()
        else:
          print("bye")  
    else:
        print("You lose...")
        continue_play = input("do you want to play again? 'y' or 'n': ")
        if continue_play == "y":
          play_blackjack()
        else:
          print("bye")  
        
  elif get_another_card == "n":
    
             *here is the error*
#The code get an error: (while computer_cards_total < 17:)  
#NameError: name 'computer_cards_total' #is not defined 

      while computer_cards_total < 17:
        computer_cards_list.append(one_cards_func())     
        computer_cards_total = calculate_score(computer_cards_list)
          
      print(f"{player_card_list} your final score: {player_card_total}") 
      print(f"{computer_cards_list} computer final score: {computer_cards_total}")
      if player_card_total <= 21 and player_card_total > computer_cards_total:
        print ("You win!!!")
        continue_play = input("do you want to play again? 'y' or 'n': ")
        if continue_play == "y":
          play_blackjack()
        else:
          print("bye")  
      else:
        print("You lose...") 
        continue_play = input("do you want to play again? 'y' or 'n': ")
        if continue_play == "y":
          play_blackjack()
        else:
          print("bye")   

if input("Do you want to play blackjack? 'y'or 'n': ") == "y":
  play_blackjack() 
else:
  print("Bye...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `global computer_cards_total`, you need to initialize `computer_cards_total` with some value like `computer_cards_total = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `computer_cards_total` is only defined in the if statement `if get_another_card == "y"`

I would recommend you define `computer_cards_total` immediately after you create `computer_cards_list` or before the while loop where the error occurs.